# What is the purpose of "-Wa,option" in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

How do I use

> -Wa,option

in GCC? What are all the options I can pass to the assembler? Is there a list of all GCC options?

For example, I found **-Wa,-a,-ad** [here](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html). What does it mean?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How'bout `man 3 gcc`?

Comment: I want to know where can I can get what all valid options can I pass to the assembler.

Comment: and there are no entries for gcc in 3rd section of man

Comment: @H2CO3: `man 1 gcc`, or `info gcc` for the full manual (if installed), or go online: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/

Comment: @DietrichEpp Right, I'm used to man 3 since library functions have their manual in there... whatever.

Comment: This seems like a real question to me. He's obviously a non-expert, and he's learning about how to use the assembler from the compiler driver.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Always check the [Documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Assembler-Options.html)

> -Wa,option
>   Pass option as an option to the assembler. If option contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.

So in your case `-a` and `-ad` were passed to the assembler, what those do depend on your assembler. Gcc doesn't know what to do with system-specific assembler options so giving it the `-Wa` flag lets it know to just pass whatever follows through.

You can also find the documentation locally via [man pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page). To open the documentation on GNU's assembler, perform:

```sh
$ man 1 as
```

It will open:

```
AS(1)                        GNU Development Tools                       AS(1)

NAME
       AS - the portable GNU assembler.

SYNOPSIS
       as [-a[cdghlns][=file]] [--alternate] [-D]
        [--compress-debug-sections]  [--nocompress-debug-sections]
        [--debug-prefix-map old=new]
        [--defsym sym=val] [-f] [-g] [--gstabs]
        [--gstabs+] [--gdwarf-2] [--gdwarf-sections]
        [--help] [-I dir] [-J]
        [-K] [-L] [--listing-lhs-width=NUM]
        [--listing-lhs-width2=NUM] [--listing-rhs-width=NUM]
        [--listing-cont-lines=NUM] [--keep-locals] [-o
        objfile] [-R] [--reduce-memory-overheads] [--statistics]
        [-v] [-version] [--version] [-W] [--warn]
        [--fatal-warnings] [-w] [-x] [-Z] [@FILE]
        [--size-check=[error|warning]]
        [--target-help] [target-options]
        [--|files ...]
        ...
```

Comment: I got that and I went through the man but my question is specific to the options -a and -ad passed to assembler

Comment: I went through this http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ but it has got nothing on the options to be passed

Comment: @user2359003 - Gcc is a compiler, it generates assembly files for your system and calls the "correct" assembler. What those flags do depend on your system/assembler, this is information you didn't specify so it's currently impossible to say what `-a` and `-ad` do. If you update then more detail can be provided.

Answer (score 3):

Since these options are passed to the assembler, you need to check the man page for `as`, not `gcc`.

`-a` turns on assembly output listings (which is written to standard output), while `-ad` omits any debugging directive from the output listing.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see a list of options of any command in bash, you can run the following command:

```
man COMMAND
```

In this case

```
man gcc
```

will reveal that `-Wa,option` means the following:

> Pass option as an option to the assembler. If option contains commas,
>   it is split into multiple options at the commas.

Comment: I got that and I went through the man but my question is specific to the options -a and -ad passed to assembler and even
I went through this gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc but it has got nothing on the options to be passed