# How to read stracktrace with CMake and Gfortran error

Tags: gcc, cmake, compiler-errors, gfortran

I'm required to install the [Dune](https://www.dune-project.org) library for my "Partial Differential Equation" lecture and am stuck. I'm on a MacBook and we received an installation script (for Linux), but I always get an error that my Gfortran and g++ compiler is not compatible.

I've researched similar errors and some could be fixed by deleting the CMake cache, but I'm not sure and don't want to screw up the folder structure.

The error code looks like this:

```
matthias@MacBookPro ~/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune$ ./buildmodules.sh
build common
----- using default flags $CMAKE_FLAGS from /Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release.opts -----
--- going to build dune-common  ---
--- calling all for dune-common ---
--- calling vcsetup for dune-common ---
--- calling configure for dune-common ---
cmake   -DDUNE_BUILD_DIRECTORY_ROOT_PATH='/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build'  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER='/usr/bin/gcc' -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER='/usr/bin/g++' -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER='/usr/local/bin/gfortran' -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE='-O3 -DNDEBUG -g0 -funroll-loops -ftemplate-depth=5120 -march=native -Wa,-q' -DHDF5_ROOT=/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/external/hdf5 -DFFTW3_ROOT_DIR=/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/external/fftw3 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DDUNE_SYMLINK_TO_SOURCE_TREE=1 "/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/dune-common"
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface.cmake:383 (message):
  The Fortran compiler:

    /usr/local/bin/gfortran

  and the CXX compiler:

    /usr/bin/g++

  failed to compile a simple test project using both languages.  The output
  was:

    Change Dir: /Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make VerifyFortranC && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/bin/cmake -S/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify -B/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 VerifyFortranC
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/bin/cmake -S/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify -B/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX/CMakeFiles 6
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/all
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/VerifyFortran.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/VerifyFortran.dir/depend
    cd /Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify /Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX /Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX /Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX/CMakeFiles/VerifyFortran.dir/DependInfo.cmake
    Scanning dependencies of target VerifyFortran
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/VerifyFortran.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/VerifyFortran.dir/build
    [ 16%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/VerifyFortran.dir/VerifyFortran.f.o
    /usr/local/bin/gfortran -DVERIFY_CXX -I/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX  -O3 -DNDEBUG -O3 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk   -c /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify/VerifyFortran.f -o CMakeFiles/VerifyFortran.dir/VerifyFortran.f.o
    [ 33%] Linking Fortran static library libVerifyFortran.a
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/VerifyFortran.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/VerifyFortran.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/ar qc libVerifyFortran.a  CMakeFiles/VerifyFortran.dir/VerifyFortran.f.o
    /usr/bin/ranlib libVerifyFortran.a
    [ 33%] Built target VerifyFortran
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/depend
    cd /Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify /Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX /Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX /Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX/CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/DependInfo.cmake
    Scanning dependencies of target VerifyFortranC
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/build
    [ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/main.c.o
    /usr/bin/gcc -DVERIFY_CXX -I/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX  -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/main.c.o   -c /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify/main.c
    [ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/VerifyC.c.o
    /usr/bin/gcc -DVERIFY_CXX -I/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX  -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/VerifyC.c.o   -c /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify/VerifyC.c
    [ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/VerifyCXX.cxx.o
    /usr/bin/g++  -DVERIFY_CXX -I/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyCXX  -std=c++17 -O3 -DNDEBUG -g0 -funroll-loops -ftemplate-depth=5120 -march=native -Wa,-q -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/VerifyCXX.cxx.o -c /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify/VerifyCXX.cxx
    clang: error: unsupported argument '-q' to option 'Wa,'
    make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/VerifyCXX.cxx.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/rule] Error 2
    make: *** [VerifyFortranC] Error 2


Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/DuneMacros.cmake:710 (FortranCInterface_VERIFY)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (dune_project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/matthias/Documents/studium_matthias/semester_7/num_2/dune/release-build/dune-common/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
--- Failed to build dune-common ---
Terminating dunecontrol due to previous errors!
```

How can I approach this?

Comment: The problem is this: `clang: error: unsupported argument '-q' to option 'Wa,'`. Why is this flag being passed in the CMake command line variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`? Do you know what its purpose is?

Comment: @squareskittles I don't know why this argument is passed. But since the installation file is for Linux this may be supported for g++ or gcc. I'm not sure. Should I just try to remove it?

Comment: The `Wa` tells the compiler to pass the option `-q` to the assembler (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423371/what-is-the-purpose-of-wa-option-in-gcc)). However, I can't find `-q` in the assembler documentation. Try removing that portion `-Wa,-q` and re-running.

Comment: @squareskittles This produces even more errors. But I think I found a solution. As you already said my Mac automatically chose clang as a compiler (where the pass to an assembler doesn't exist). I changed the used compiler from clang to gcc and currently it looks promising.

Comment: @squareskittles Thank you! Without you I would've never thought about changing the compiler.

Comment: Glad it is working! Please consider writing a quick answer to your question, and marking as accepted, to explain to others with the same issue what you changed to resolve it.

Comment: @squareskittles Thanks again. I posted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

As @squareskittles pointed out in the comments, the error arised from the unsupported argument `-q` to `Wa,`. This tells the compiler (gcc!) to pass the option `-q` to the assembler. 
This option is not supported by clang. `which gcc` told me gcc was installed and located at `/usr/bin/gcc` but further inspection showed that it was just a symlink to clang - even though I had gcc installed via homebrew (located at `/usr/local/bin/gcc-9`). 
In the installation file I was able to change the path of used compiler to the gcc installation (g++ was linked to clang, and I replaced it as well). From that point on the `-q` argument to `Wa` was valid the installation process went without further errors.

Answer (score 0):

it will fine install dune core modules using homebrew package manager for your system. From now is available 2.7.1. https://github.com/dune-copasi/homebrew-tap